# Rate limit API requests in Sanic and append remaining number to response

Tags: python-3.x, rate-limiting, sanic

I am trying to implement rate limiting for requests in Sanic. Unfortunately, the [`sanic-limiter` package](https://github.com/bohea/sanic-limiter) on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sanic-limiter/) has not been maintained for years and is not working with current Sanic versions.

I found some [GitHub fork](https://github.com/Omegastick/sanic-limiter) of that package, which can be used to set a global request limit by defining a limiter:

```
limiter = Limiter(
        app,
        global_limits = [
            "1 per second",
            "500 per day"
            ],
        key_func = get_remote_address
    )
```

I couldn't get other parts of the exampes working; thus, I assume that version of `sanic-limiter` is also not fully compatible with current Sanic versions.
According to the description, `sanic-limiter` is supposed to be the Sanic version of `Flask-Limiter`, which is linked in the references of the repo.

`Flask-Limiter` provided the functionality I am interested in, as described in [the docs](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#keyfunc-customization):

```
@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    if limiter.current_limit:
        response.headers["RemainingLimit"] = limiter.current_limit.remaining
        response.headers["ResetAt"] = limiter.current_limit.reset_at
        response.headers["MaxRequests"] = limiter.current_limit.limit.amount
        response.headers["WindowSize"] = limiter.current_limit.limit.get_expiry()
        response.headers["Breached"] = limiter.current_limit.breached
    return response
```

I tried to translate this into `Sanic` like this:

```
    @app.middleware("response")
    async def add_headers(request, response):
        if limiter.current_limit:
            response.headers["RemainingIDs"] = str(
                limiter.current_limit.remaining
                )
            
            response.headers["ResetAt"] = str(
                limiter.current_limit.reset_at
                )
        
        return response
```

but the `limiter` apparently does not have those attributes.

Now, I wondered whether anybody got some rate limit working on a current `Sanic` version and knows how to return the number of remaining requests. Unfortunately, `sanic-limiter` is barely documented and probably does not provide all required functionalities. So, maybe you know an alternative to `sanic-limiter` or some work-around?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I've got this repo on the side I built for rate limiting I'm Sanic. I still need to put it on pypi, but maybe it will help. https://github.com/ahopkins/sanic-bucket

Comment: Hi there! I rewrote a package someone wrote for FastAPI (which was significantly smaller than the Flask version) here: https://github.com/DenSinH/sanic-rate-limiter. I am not sure if it works perfectly, but I just tested it a bit and I think I am going to use it for my project.